# How to create a datasource for mongodb in websphere

Tags: mongodb, websphere

Can some one help in providing steps for creating a datasource for mongodb in websphere

Comment: The MongoDB Java driver website has this [info and examples about JNDI (Java Naming and Directory Interface)](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/tutorials/jndi/) which is used to configure the data source for MongoDB database. Note that the examples are for Apache Tomcat and JBoss/Wildfly application servers - I think you can use the details and apply for WebSphere. Further, it helps if you include MongoDB server, Java Driver and WebSphere versions in your post.

Answer (score 0):

A recommended approach for using the MongoDB java driver in WebSphere Application Server Liberty is documented here:
https://openliberty.io/blog/2019/02/19/mongodb-with-open-liberty.html

If you are using traditional WebSphere Application Server rather than Liberty, the CDI aspect of the approach is all standard and will work there as well, however, the MicroProfile Config part would not be available.